# How keras model H5 works in theory

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

After training the trained model will be saved as H5 format. But I didn't know how that H5 file can be used as classifier to classifying new data. How H5 model works in theory when classifying new data?

Comment: You have to load the model back again in a python script and then execute it, you should check this check out https://pythonprogramming.net/using-trained-model-deep-learning-python-tensorflow-keras/ and other videos in the series

Comment: No, I mean how the h5 model process the new data to be classified

Answer (score 1):

When you save your model as h5-file, you save the model structure, all its parameters and further informations like state of your optimizer and so on. It is just an efficient way to save huge amounts of information. You could use json or xml file formats to do this as well.

You can't classifiy anything only using this file (it is not executable). You have to rebuild the graph as a tensorflow graph from this file. To do so you simply use the load_model() function from keras, which returns a keras.models.Model object. Then you can use this object to classifiy new data, with keras predict() function.

Comment: How data from new image flowing through the model to become probabilities?

Comment: You can load your images with opencv or skimage or PILL and turn them into numpy arrays. Then you can simply call my_model.predict(img_array).

Answer (score 0):

nice question,

first  you need to understand what is HDF5 file are, because this is essentielle if you want an answer to your question see this link : [What is HDF5](https://www.neonscience.org/about-hdf5)

for know just know  that it's a little complicated type of files that hold all the necessary information for the model you trained.

but it's not an  executable so it can be used only as an input for function along with image you want to classify "after the proper preprocessing for the image",

then from the information in the HDF5 file and the image,a sequence of operations will occur then returning the probabilities of the classes as a result of the operations.

for example out of the deep learning frameworks we can use the model.h5 in web app using tensorflow.js for example and the function responsible of doing this is "model.predict" from "tensorflow library".

this is source code in javascript will help you make this point clear:
the hdf5 file was converted to JSON because this is the supported format in tensorflow.js.

if you want to know more about tensorflow.js : [youtube playlist by deeplizard](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZbbT5o_s2xr83l8w44N_g3pygvajLrJ-)

also as you see, we can convert HDF5 files to JSON files and this make it more clear, I think!

```
model = await tf.loadModel("model.json");

let tensor = tf.fromPixels(image)
    .resizeNearestNeighbor([224,224])
    .toFloat();

let predictions = await model.predict(tensor).data();
    let top5 = Array.from(predictions)
        .map(function (p, i) { // this is Array.map
            return {
                probability: p,
                className: CLASSES[i] // we are selecting the value from the obj
            };
}).sort(function (a, b)
```

I hope this was helpful just read the article I mentioned and a lote of this will make sense.